# Northwind - creating orders (MySQL + Spring boot)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have DB with schema like below: 
[image]

I would like to create an Order. I created DAO of Order with all columns like below and added there relations like this:

**Order**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="OrderID", nullable = false,unique = true)
    private Integer orderID;

// here attributes from Columns I am skipping it

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
    public Set<OrderDetails> getOrderDetails() {
        return orderDetails;
    }

    public void setOrderDetails(Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails) {
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
    }
```

I am wondering now how can I create POST with order details. I tried it that way:

**OrderService**

```
public void createOrUpdateOrder(Order order){
    Set<OrderDetails> orderDetailsSet = new HashSet<>();

    for( OrderDetails orderDetails : order.getOrderDetails() ) {
        orderDetails.setOrder( order );
        orderDetails.setOrderID(order.getOrderID()); // HERE IS NULL, orderID is not set yet, maybe thats the reason
    }
    order.setOrderDetails( orderDetailsSet );
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

but that way when I GET all Orders with OrderDetails I can see that for each order orderDetails value is empty.

Here is my example POST payload:

```
{
"customerID":"ANATR",
"employeeID": 3,
"orderDate": "1996-07-10",
"requiredDate": "1996-07-24",
"shippedDate": "1996-07-16",
"shipVia": 2,
"freight": 58.17,
"shipName": "Hanari Carnes",
"shipAddress": "Rua do Paço, 67",
"shipCity": "Rio de Janeiro",
"shipRegion": "RJ",
"shipPostalCode": "05454-876",
"shipCountry": "Brazil",
"orderDetails":[
    {
         "unitPrice": 9,
         "quantity": 10,
         "discount": 0,
         "productID":12
    }
    ]
}
```

and my response for GET order:

```
    "orderID": 1000019,
    "customerID": "ANATR",
    "employeeID": 3,
    "orderDate": "1996-07-10",
    "requiredDate": "1996-07-24",
    "shippedDate": "1996-07-16",
    "shipVia": 2,
    "freight": 58.17,
    "shipName": "Hanari Carnes",
    "shipAddress": "Rua do Paço, 67",
    "shipCity": "Rio de Janeiro",
    "shipRegion": "RJ",
    "shipPostalCode": "05454-876",
    "shipCountry": "Brazil",
    "orderDetails": []  <----- should not be empty!
```

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try joining table with FetchMode **JOIN** relationship.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
```

Comment: It didnt help :( I found out that I am not saving orderDetails . Like with ```orderRepository.save(order)``` I think I have to do the asme for orderDetails : ```orderDetailsRepository.save(orderDetails)``` . Am I right? I think issue is that autogenerated ID for orderID, so orderDetails dont know it is value and it is null

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` to your `Order` field in `OrderDetails` entity, that way hibernate will know how to connect those two entities when saving both of them.

The `createOrUpdateOrder` method will then just look like this:

```
public Integer createOrUpdateOrder(Order order){
    Order newOrder = orderRepository.save(order);
    return newOrder.getOrderID();
}
```